# How to centre elements in Jetpack Compose Desktop Column

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, desktop-application

Working on desktop application with Jetpack Compose and unable to center elements in a `Column` as `horizontalAlignment` attribute is not working. I've also seen many other answers saying to use `horizontalArrangment` but that is also not working for desktop application.

[image]

Update: I've imported `Alignment` from `androidx.compose.ui` now and able to use `CenterHorizontally` and error is gone but it's still not getting in centre.

Comment: You have imported `Alignment` from a wrong package. It should be from `androidx.compose.ui`, and `Alignment.Center` instead of `CENTER`. If this solves your problem, you can remove this question as it's not gonna help anyone else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add

```
Column(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth(),
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CENTRE
){
   ....
}
```

because u need to state max width for the apps or you need to define the width/height of the column so that horizontal can be placed on the centre.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **Align.CenterHorizontally** and add it if you don't want to check your import

```
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment

Column (
      modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
      verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
      horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
      //content here
    }
```